# Why XMLns doesn't work on my vim?

Tags: vim

I have been trying to use XMLns to enable schema autocomplete on vim, but the command is not recognized. When I try, vim returns:

E492: Not an editor command: XMLns

I'm using the vim 8.1 installed from Manjaro repository.

Anyone can help me make XMLns work?

Thank you

Comment: What did you actually do to make it work? What did you do to run it from within vim?

Comment: :XMLns gives me that error, but even when I try to tab complete it doesn't seem to find anything.

Comment: [How to run Unix commands from within Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/285500/how-to-run-unix-commands-from-within-vim) might be relevant. It's still unclear what your setup looks like and what you're trying to achieve. What tools or scripts you additionally installed, what you expect to work differently and so on.

Comment: I am trying to make this work http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-xml-omni so I can get schema aware autocompletion in vim.

Comment: Did you check that the autoload directory contains the appropriate files? Did you try to enter the correct mode before using that command?

Comment: I thought this functionality was embedded in vim. What do I need to setup in the autoload dir? I run this command in Normal Mode.

Comment: It's right there on the page you linked. It does need `xml-omni-datafile`. They could be default but checking whenever they exist or not might be worth it.

Comment: I have tried once again but I don't think the command XMLns is even available in my vim. Maybe is it the way my vim is compiled (I used the standard one from Manjo reps)

Comment: Make sure you have `:filetype` plugins enabled. The standard xml filetype distributed with Vim still defines a `XMLns` command, so it should work for you.

Comment: When I do :filetype I get filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON so it seems to be enabled.